# POSTMAN Script Raw Data Input

Tags: postman-pre-request-script

I an trying to send Raw data to populate fields, the main one i need to populate is "additional info" but due to multiple variables being in additional info, im getting a syntax error

Below is what i have tried to do

Works fine if additional info is removed

```
{
"hostname":"TW_OF0048_CS01.thameswater.co.uk","severity":"1","description":" Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8 - Gi1/0/8 for node TW_OF0048_CS01.thameswater.co.uk is Down.","icon":"Red","source":"SolarWinds"
}
```

gets syntax error

```
    "additonal_info":{"hostname":"","networkNodeId":"1805","swEventId":"1274896","icon":"Red","netObjectId":"14592","NetObjectType":"I","eventType":"10"}
```

I need to pass both to ServiceNow.

I have tried various different ways to try and get it to work but always get some sort of error

```
{
"hostname":"TW_OF0048_CS01.thameswater.co.uk","severity":"1","description":" Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8 - Gi1/0/8 for node TW_OF0048_CS01.thameswater.co.uk is Down.","icon":"Red","source":"SolarWinds"
}
```

gets syntax error

```
    "additonal_info":{"hostname":"","networkNodeId":"1805","swEventId":"1274896","icon":"Red","netObjectId":"14592","NetObjectType":"I","eventType":"10"}
```

It should come into ServiceNow like the below

Comment: Not clear what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like you are putting "additional_info" in as a proper json object. Try wrapping it in curly's. If that doesn't help what is the syntax error?

```
{
"additonal_info":{"hostname":"","networkNodeId":"1805","swEventId":"1274896","icon":"Red","netObjectId":"14592","NetObjectType":"I","eventType":"10"}
}
```